# Is it possible to subscribe to subscriptions in apache pulsar?

Tags: apache-pulsar

Motivation:
Given a producer for particular set of topics, A*.
The producer should only generate the A* messages if there are active subscribers to those A* topics.

Question:
Do subscriptions generate messages on a topic?

Comment: I found the https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/2.11.x/concepts-messaging/#system-topic which appears to be the place to look.

Comment: Producers are intended to be completely decoupled from consumers on the same topics. It is reasonable for a producer to publish some messages on a topic that should be consumed in the future. Therefore, adding such a requirement (for an active) subscription would couple the producer to a consumer. Furthermore, by default, Pulsar does NOT retain messages on a topic without active consumers. This is to prevent unbounded message storage.

Comment: Consider video streaming a movie vs. streaming from a robot. Each image being a separate message. In the case of the movie the video may be published and no frames may be dropped; would you want to publish the video stream if there were no consumers?

Comment: In that analogy, the movie contents would be the sequence of image frames stored as individual messages on the topic. Consumers then connect to the topic and read the images individually to "view" the movie. If they wanted to pause the movie, they would stop consuming. When they were ready to resume watching again, they would pick up from where they had left off. This consumption pattern would be write-once-read-many-times where the producer writes the data once, and future readers can consume the data at their own pace.

Comment: Right, but it may be that the producer does not want to publish if there turn out to be no subscribers.

Comment: If you want to check whether there are subscriptions on a topic, you can use the getSubscriptions() method of the Admin API (https://pulsar.apache.org/api/admin/2.11.x/org/apache/pulsar/client/admin/Topics.html#getSubscriptions(java.lang.String)). An empty list would indicate no active subscriptions.